# what is the return value of the function that returns int, but isn't returning anything explicitly. for instance output of

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, stack, stack-trace

```
int fun()
{
 printf("\ncrap");
}


void main()
{
  printf("\n return value of fun %d", fun());
}
```

and please, can you explain on how the stack allocates the memory for return values and how the stack works here.

Comment: I know it is architecture dependent, but, I am asking for a general thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fun` triggers **undefined behaviour**.

Please *always compile with all compiler warnings enabled*. That should give you a warning that you are making that very mistake.

Your `main` is also triggering undefined behaviour because the C++ standard demands that there be only one single function called `main` and it return `int`. However, you are allowed, as a special case, to omit the `return` statement in your (corrected) `main` function.

"The stack", as you presume, is not part of the C++ language. But that's irrelevant; the standard says that the returned object is constructed in the scope of the caller, which is all you need to know.

(Practically, an unreturned `int` is probably going to end up like an uninitialized variable of type `int`, but the standard says that the function call already triggers the undefined behaviour, not just read-access later on.)

Comment: Nah, always compile with *some* compiler warnings enabled. Including this one ;-) (+1, though)

Comment: So, you mean that anything could get printed??... With -Wall it does give warning... But, I am curious to know about the stack... I mean what is stored on the stack??

Comment: @Invictus: Well, since `%d` means "type `int`", I suppose yes, any *integer value* could get printed. "Undefined behaviour" actually means that the program could behave in any way, at all (crash, format your hard disk, order pizza). Practically though I imagine you'll always make it to the `printf` line. Michael: I meant something like `-Wall`; not necessarily "all obscure and questionable warnings". Brevity is the soul of nit, eh?

Answer (score 2):

That's undefined behaviour. Anything could happen.

Answer (score 2):

As it is architecture dependant, there is no general thing.

However, it can be admitted that the value that is computed last, or the returned value from the last called function *can* be returned. But in the end it is **undefined behavior**. If you want to rely on it ...

Note also that there is a special case for `int main()`. (Btw: `void main()` is not standard.) If no return statement is present, it returns `0`.